# no match for 'operator+' in basic_string <char> and uchar

Tags: c++, string, casting, char, operators

I'm trying to create a concatenated string using a `basic_string<char>` and a `uchar*` (`unsigned char*`). I'm running into issues and have tried every method possible.

My code looks like this at the send:

```
system("command " + std::basic_string <char> + uchar*)
```

This is how my code basically look. Any way I can successfully concatenate the strings and do the operation?

One error among others is:

> no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::basic_string' and 'uchar*')

Comment: Please show a [mre]. What are you actually trying to do? Do you know that `std::basic_string <char>` is exactly the same as `std::string`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm aware. I just want to concanate the strings in the system command

Comment: Have you tried building the command string before calling `system`?  You could use `std::ostringstream`.  You would then call `system(command_options.c_str())`.  A nice benefit of this technique is that you can place a breakpoint at the `system` statement and verify the command text is correct.

Comment: Hey @ThomasMatthews I have that doesn't fix the ```'operator+' (operand types are std::basic_string and uchar*)``` bug though. I just want to know how to properly cast the two to concante them.

Comment: You are doing things wrong then.  The `std::ostringstream` doesn't require the `operator+` at all.

Comment: @JustinYoungTech Why are you using `unsigned char*` in the first place? Where is that coming from, exactly? Please provide a [mcve]. `std::string` doesn't accept `unsigned char` characters, only `char` characters.  So, if you must use `unsigned char*` then you will have to type-cast the data when concatenating it